# Terraform: Cannot create spot instance. Error: MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ec2-spot-market

I am trying to create a spot instance in Terraform and the terraform code appears to be fine but I keep getting an error back saying *MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded*.

NOTE: Right now this is just a test hence I am not including security groups, IPs, etc etc.

Steps I have taken:

1. Checked that I have 0 spot instance requests created in console.
2. Tried logging in to the console and creating a spot instance request. It works just fine.
3. Cancelled the spot instance request to ensure that I now have 0 spot instance requests.
4. Now I try and create virtually the same spot instance with the terraform script below, but I get the error: *MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded*

Does anyone know why Terraform (or maybe AWS?) is not allowing me to create the spot instance using the terraform script, but it works just fine from the console?

Thanks!

```
provider "aws" {
profile = "terraform_enterprise_user"
region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "MySpotInstance" {

# Spot Request Settings
wait_for_fulfillment = "true"
spot_type = "persistent"
instance_interruption_behaviour = "stop"


# Instance Settings
ami = "ami-0520e698dd500b1d1"
instance_type = "c4.large"
associate_public_ip_address = "1"

root_block_device {
    volume_size = "10"
    volume_type = "standard"
}

ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sdb"
    volume_size = "50"
    volume_type = "standard"
    delete_on_termination = "true"
}

tags = {
    Name = "MySpotInstance"
    Application = "MyApp"
    Environment = "TEST"
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Spot Instance Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217134/aws-spot-instance-limit)

Comment: Sometimes, an AZ may run out of specific EC2 instance class, and the error message from Terraform may not be reflecting it. Does the issue happen consistently after taking a few hours?

Comment: Does it happen with other instance type other than c4.large?

Comment: Run the script and worked having created RHEL-8.0.0_HVM-20190618-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2 (ami-0520e698dd500b1d1) in AZ-a in Ohio region. So code is not the issue. Please try creating the same spot instance from console?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html

Comment: Yeah it looks like it is one of the service limits in Amazon. In this case the error is self explanatory but I have seen other Terraform error messages that are not directly indicative of the issue at hand, hence I decided to ask the question in this forum.

I have reached out to AWS to have them increase the service limit so hopefully that fixes it. Thanks for all the answers! :)